# How can I create a Register Page in Xcode?

Tags: .net, objective-c, json, xcode, post

So I'm working on creating a register page. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to take the STRING of username for example and putting it inside of the parameters section. Without hardcoding it.  Right now its hardcoded as username@yahoo.com and password1. I want to be able to take everything entered above and put it in the parameters section so it can be sent to the server.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.
My Code is below:

```
- (IBAction)signUp:(id)sender {

if ([userName.text isEqualToString:@""] || [email.text isEqualToString:@""] || [emailPublic.text isEqualToString:@""] ||[password.text isEqualToString:@""] || [passwordHint.text isEqualToString:@""] || [avatar.text isEqualToString:@""] || [sex.text isEqualToString:@""] || [dob.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Please fill in all the fields!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

   NSURL *url = [NSURLURLWithString:@"http://WEBSITEHERE/api/users/AuthenticateUser"];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   NSString *parameters = @" {\"userName\":\"username@yahoo.com\",\"password\":\"password1\"}";

    NSLog(@"PARAMS = %@", parameters);   

    NSData *data = [parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:data];     

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;

    NSError *error = nil;    

    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

NSLog(@"RESULT = %@", responseString);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to construct the JSON data "manually". That's error prone because the
strings might contain characters that have to be escaped in the JSON.

Better create a dictionary and use
`NSJSONSerialization`:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"userName": userName.text, @"password": password.text};
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. If I could trouble you with one last question. I've posted it here. I can't seem to login. And not sure what i'm doing wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622006/how-can-i-create-a-login-page-in-xcode